# Validation rule on Trigger - Help!

Tags: apex, salesforce-classic

Any help would be much appreciated here!

I am wanting to create a trigger to run a validation rule on the Account object bascially stating when the Account has a certain record type and doesn't have a salutation don't allow create. We cannot use a standard validation rule as we use an Override when creating Accounts that points at a Visualforce page - so it has to be a trigger.

Here what I have so far.

```
trigger validation_using_Trigger on Account (before insert) {
 for(Account acc:trigger.new){
    if(acc.recordtype.name == 'UK_Person')
        acc.salutation = '';
       acc.adderror('Please add Salutation');
    }
 }
```

The rule does throw an error message, however it ignores the record type and salutation. What am I doing wrong here?

You've probably gathered I new to code, so go easy!

Cheers,
Liam

Comment: Are you sure you cannot use a validation rule? The validation rule is applied when a record is inserted/updated in the database, irrespective where (API, Apex, regular user interface, process builder, etc) and a Visualforce override wouldn't change that.

Comment: I see - then yes we could! which would save a whole bunch of time! Now... on further inspection, the validation rule doesn't seem to be picking up the record type which is bizarre. I have tried both the ID and name fields but still no luck, any thoughts?

Comment: My guess is you are using the developername in the string, and checking for the Name field (the label of the record type). Either change acc.recordtype.name to acc.recordtype.developername, or check for the label (preferably you check for the developername)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally validation rule should suffice your needs. Even if your create/edit page is overridden by a visualforce page, you can still show an error message to user in page by adding `<apex:pageMessages/>` tag.

Validation rule should be

```
AND(RecordType.DeveloperName =='UK_Person',ISBLANK(Salutation))
```

But, if you still want to achieve this using trigger, then following are the changes you need to do in your code

- `acc.RecordType.Name` will not be accessible in trigger as it is a `relationship field` i.e. only fields that are part of the `object` that is in transaction are accessible in `context variables`. Hence that particular `field` won't be accessible.
- Instead you can use `acc.RecordTypeId` and get the `name` of the record type using [RecordTypeInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_RecordTypeInfo.htm) class and use it for comparison.

So your trigger code should be

```
trigger validation_using_Trigger on Account (before insert) {
    string recordTypeName = '';
    for(Account acc:trigger.new){
        recordTypeName = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosById().get(acc.RecordTypeId).getDeveloperName();
        if('UK_Person'.equalsIgnoreCase(recordTypeName) && string.isBlank(acc.Salutation))
            acc.adderror('Please add Salutation');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are a god! Thankyou so much, spent hours on this! Useful to know about the record types, I am sure this will come up again in the future!

Answer (score 1):

In order to correctly identify if a field is "blank", I suggest you use the [String](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) class.

Here is an example of validating that a field contains a value:

```
trigger validation_using_Trigger on Account (before insert) {
    for(Account acc : trigger.new) {
        if (String.isBlank(acc.Description)) {
            acc.adderror('Please add a Description.'); 
        }
    }
}
```

Using the `isBlank()` method on the `String` class, as per the documentation:

> Returns true if the specified String is white space, empty (''), or
>   null; otherwise, returns false.

You have a compile issue with the code provided in your question. `acc.salutation = '';`, Salutation is not a standard field on Account.

Answer (score 1):

Although I still think you should be able to solve your use case with a validation rule (which will also save you the hassle of writing test classes), this is what is going wrong in your code:

```
if(acc.recordtype.name == 'UK_Person')
        acc.salutation = '';
       acc.adderror('Please add Salutation');
}
```

You need to include the check for `Salutation` in the evaluation part of the if statement:

```
trigger validation_using_Trigger on Account (before insert) {

   for(Account acc:trigger.new) {
        if(acc.recordtype.name == 'UK_Person' && acc.salutation = '') {
           acc.adderror('Please add Salutation');
        }
    }
 }
```

Also, because you didn't wrap the `acc.addError()` part  in the braces (see my example), it didn't see it as part of the if statement. It's outside the if statement, thus executes it always.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Folkert. You should be able to achieve this with validation rule

There's an attribute on `commandButtons` called `immediate`. If you set that to false, validation will be fired.